# FutureBuilder makes UI freeze

Tags: flutter, dart, freeze

I want to load the songs i have in my phone using a FutureBuilder, in order to show a loading page. The page in which showing all the songs is wrapped inside a TabBar, which is part of a PageView. It happens that, when i move from a page to another, the FutureBuilder seems to freeze the UI, waiting for the operation to finish. I can't figure out what i'm doing wrong. I report here my code and a video which demonstrates the freeze.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hlwj6TKACLc
I put a video to make the problem the clearest possible. As you can notice, the CircularProgressIndicator freezes as every UI component

```
class MusicPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State createState() {
    return _MusicPageState();
  }
}

class _MusicPageState extends State<MusicPage> with 
TickerProviderStateMixin {
  Future<dynamic> _songs;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    TabController controller = TabController(
      length: 3,
      vsync: this,
    );

return Scaffold(
    appBar: TabBar(
        isScrollable: true,
        controller: controller,
        indicatorColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
        tabs: widget.tabs),
    body: TabBarView(controller: controller, children: <Widget>[
      FutureBuilder(
          future: _songs,
          builder: (context, snapshot){
            switch(snapshot.connectionState){
              case ConnectionState.done:
                return Center(child: Text('done'),);

              case ConnectionState.active:
              case ConnectionState.none:
              case ConnectionState.waiting:
                return CircularProgressIndicator();
            }
      }),
      AlbumsGrid(
        albums: AlbumUtils.getCachedAllAlbums(),
      ),
      AuthorsList(
        authors: widget.authors,
      )
    ]));
   }

  @override
   void initState() {
    _songs = MusicFinder.allSongs();
    super.initState();
  }
 }
```

I expect it not to focus on the Future loading (like it was synchronous), obviously showing what it's meant to be a waiting indicator.
Last things: i omitted some variables to focus on the FutureBuilder part. Don't mind them.

Thanks everyone in advance.

Comment: We need the code in `MusicFinder.allSongs()`

Comment: MusicFinder is a Flutter plugin, you can find the function here: https://github.com/konaken73/Musicfinder/blob/master/AndroidStudioProjects/musicfinder/lib/musicfinder.dart

Comment: You're doing heavy operations in the main thread, consider doing them in a separate isloate (use the `compute` function). [Here](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/background-parsing#4-move-this-work-to-a-separate-isolate)'s an example.

Comment: In the end, i chose to adopt another approach, using singletons and providers.
Anyway, i had to use the FutureBuilder in a simpler context (just a StatefulWidget which shows some data into itself when a button is pressed), and it worked perfectly through the same implementation, as above. I suppose this is a not-properly handled situation in Flutter's scheduling core.
Meanwhile, i also think the one who downvoted my question did not read it properly.

Answer (score 0):

I would say the problem is not with the `FutureBuilder` itself, but with `AlbumUtils.getCachedAllAlbums()`. Being that you call it in the `build` tree, it is called on every drawn frame, and the frame does not finish loading until that method is done. I would suggest trying to move `getCachedAllAlbums()` outside the `build` method.